# Deserialize json filed to a different Java Object with Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using Google Places in my app. When I requests the nearby places I get a list of places. Every places have this Json structure:

```
{
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.870775,
           "lng" : 151.199025
        }
     },
     ...
}
```

My Java `Place` class instead is declared in this way:

```
public class Place {
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;
   ...
}
```

How can I assign the `lat` json field to the `latitude` member and `lng` to `longitude`? Is it possible using `Gson` or should I create a Geometry class and a Location class too?

I tried with these serialized name but it is not working:

```
@SerializedName("geometry.location.lat") private double latitude;
@SerializedName("geometry.location.lng") private double longitude;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution that I see is to implement a custom **JsonDeserializer**. Also it's worth separating classes that you are using for communication with external services and your domain objects. Then you will have some class **GooglePlace**, your domain class **Place** and also an adapter(converter) to transform GooglePlace to Place and backwards. In this case you implementation will be more flexible.

Comment: I'm with you on that +1. For an example of a custom deserializer, I created this gist: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/206943e377d719121e2f

Comment: Perfect! This gist clearly reveals the idea. But anyway I think in many situations it's a good idea to separate transfer objects from the ones that are used for business layer.